# for loop method to extract speicific part of dictionary

Tags: python

hi i am new to python and trying to parse this dictionary using for loop and fetch git url, but i am unable

Here is the Dictionary

```
interface={
    provides=[Quic_implementation]
    packages = [
        { packageName = 'lsQuic'
          fetchMethod = 'git:https://github.com/litespeedtech/lsquic.git:commit=7fc1254' // could start with git, zip, file, system, etc. (system = apt install lib...)
          updateWhen  = 'never'    // Updating isn't implemented
          buildCmds   = [
              [linux,   'cmake . && make', ['src/lsquic.a',   'includes/lsquic.h']], // How to build and files to install for Linux
              [windows, 'cmake . && make', ['src/lsquic.dll', 'includes/lsquic.h']]
          ]
        },
```

Right now i am getting this

```
'lsQuic'
'crypto'
'zlib'
'system'
```

but i want following git url in 'lsquic'

```
fetchMethod = 'git:https://github.com/litespeedtech/lsquic.git:commit=7fc1254'
```

here is loop i am using

```
interfaceTags = progSpec.fetchTagValue([libTags], 'interface')
    #
    fetchtags = progSpec.fetchTagValue([interfaceTags], 'packages')
    packagesTags = progSpec.fetchTagValue([fetchtags], 'packageName')

    if interfaceTags:
        if 'packages' in interfaceTags:
            fetchtags = progSpec.fetchTagValue([interfaceTags], 'packages')

            for i in range(len(fetchtags)):
                name = fetchtags[i][1][0][1][0]
                print(name)
```

Comment: `//` isn't a valid comment indicator in Python. Your dictionary layout is invalid and there's a random indent. This script wouldn't run at all

Comment: It is not python code, it is another library, also my code is running i am able to fetch data but i want in specific order.

Comment: You need to provide the input in correct format. That isn't a python dictionary at all.

Comment: Why is this tagged as python then? You also specifically mention python in your question, without referencing any other languages. Am I missing something? If it's another library, then why haven't you specified it? How do you expect people to help?

Answer (score 0):

The Dictionary you gave us isn't a Dictionary at all. I fixed it for you:

```py
data = {
    "interface": {
        "provides": ["Quic_implementation"],
        "packages": [
            {
                "packageName": "lsQuic",
                "fetchMethod": "git:https://github.com/litespeedtech/lsquic.git:commit=7fc1254",
                "updateWhen": "never",
                "buildCmds": [
                    ["linux",   "cmake . && make", ["src/lsquic.a",   "includes/lsquic.h"]],
                    ["windows", "cmake . && make", ["src/lsquic.dll", "includes/lsquic.h"]]
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If you don't get a Dictionary but some Text that looks like what you showed us, you first need to convert it. Alternatively, you can also take the way of text splitting and getting the info you need like this. But that won't work if the format changes a bit.

In case you actually get a Dictionary like the one I showed you, you can get the "fetchMethod" like this:

```py
fetchMethods = []
for package in data["interface"]["packages"]:
    fetchMethods.append(package["fetchMethod"])

print(fetchMethods)
```